# How to force vim cursor always shape Block

Tags: neovim

I use astronvim for nvim config, but it change the cursor to bar when in insert mode. Is there a way to force the cursor to be block at any mode?

I try to find some help in vim manual, `:help cursor`, but I can't find anything helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `set guicursor=` to your `init.vim`.

Citing [Neovim FAQ](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/wiki/FAQ#how-to-change-cursor-shape-in-the-terminal):

> For Nvim 0.2 or newer: cursor styling is controlled by the `guicursor` option.
>
> - To disable cursor-styling, set guicursor to empty:
>
> ```
> set guicursor=
> " Workaround some broken plugins which set guicursor indiscriminately.
> :autocmd OptionSet guicursor noautocmd set guicursor=
> ```